# Apache Cordova app with html5 canvas -- drag no longer working after android upgrade

Tags: android, cordova, canvas, html5-canvas

I have an html5 canvas element where I recognize the touch location of a finger to determine whether or not an element in the canvas is touched.  it was working just fine and then I upgraded my version of android to 4.4.2 on my samsung s4 and nexus 7.  Now touch events are working as expected BUT the dragging is no longer working.  Anyone else run into this problem?  I disabled the webbounce and overscroll in the config.xml properties file.

Comment: I've come across this but only sporadically. Did you find a solution?